# How to let Mercurial show "hg out --patch" diff as visual diff?

Tags: mercurial, diff

It looks like `hg out --patch` or `hg out -p` is a good way to see what code is pushed out to the repo (when it is pushed)...  but the diff is in text format.  Is there a way to make it use `kdiff3` as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a way to pipe the git or Mercurial diff output to a GUI Diff tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954118/is-there-a-way-to-pipe-the-git-or-mercurial-diff-output-to-a-gui-diff-tool)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hg outgoing --patch` shows the changes in each changeset separately, which probably isn't what you want if you're looking for a visual representation.  You more likely want the GUI equivalent of `hg diff -r your_latest_changeset -r remote_servers_latest_changeset` where the latest changesets are the respective `tip` revisions if you're not using named branches.  You can get that in your favorite GUI using the [extdiff extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) yielding a final command like:

```
hg extdiff -p kdiff3 -r your_latest_changeset -r remote_servers_latest_changeset
```

Comment: hm... what if Peter and Mary both modified 200 lines, won't those show in the above command line?  What if just diff'ing between your current code with "the pulled version"?  was asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202622/using-mercurial-how-to-diff-with-a-fixed-revision-if-commit-intermediate-states

Answer (score 0):

```
$ hg out --patch | mdr
```

Will give you a graphical view

You'll need [MDR](http://readablediff.com) (mac and win)

Comment: The MDR link is dead