# Mercurial - view diff of all files in all changesets listed in hg out?

Tags: mercurial

We have repositories proj & proj_v1.  When we do this:

```
cd c:\proj
hg fetch ..\proj_v1
hg out
```

We see a list of changesets from proj_v1 that we pulled into proj along with an "auto merge" changeset from the requisite merge.

What Mercurial command can you use to see a diff of all files in all changesets that are listed in the output of `hg out`?

We'd like to review all changes that would be pushed to proj when we do an `hg push`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would something like `hg out -p` work for you?

Comment: That appears to work.. BUT I wanted to use my visual diff tool (configured using hgext.extdiff).. can't see how to use this command with the diff tool

Comment: @Marcus: try looking at the accepted answer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209372/how-to-let-mercurial-show-hg-out-patch-diff-as-visual-diff

Answer (score 2):

Use: `hg out -p` (or `--patch`).

Comment: That appears to work..  BUT I wanted to use my visual diff tool (configured using hgext.extdiff)..  can't see how to use this command with the diff tool